# How can I predict a 2d output in keras (label shape = 20, 42, 3)

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have a hand pose estimation dataset (RHD dataset). The inputs are RGB images (320x320x3) and a single label has this shape (42, 3):

```
array([[ 0.05283 ,  0.05878 ,  0.6696  ],
   [-0.05483 ,  0.08679 ,  0.5844  ],
   [-0.03584 ,  0.08737 ,  0.6015  ],
   [-0.01452 ,  0.08199 ,  0.6239  ],
   [ 0.02035 ,  0.07135 ,  0.6479  ],
   [-0.01679 ,  0.07526 ,  0.5043  ],
   [-0.00701 ,  0.06789 ,  0.5283  ],
   [ 0.002691,  0.06231 ,  0.5502  ],
   [ 0.01555 ,  0.06194 ,  0.5836  ],
   [ 0.02368 ,  0.06908 ,  0.4946  ],
   [ 0.02951 ,  0.06739 ,  0.52    ],
   [ 0.03332 ,  0.05871 ,  0.5455  ],
   [ 0.0389  ,  0.05864 ,  0.5797  ],
   [ 0.05521 ,  0.07793 ,  0.5055  ],
   [ 0.05739 ,  0.07229 ,  0.5305  ],
   [ 0.05845 ,  0.06505 ,  0.5556  ],
   [ 0.05725 ,  0.06129 ,  0.5846  ],
   [ 0.08927 ,  0.08603 ,  0.5338  ],
   [ 0.08616 ,  0.08226 ,  0.5512  ],
   [ 0.08332 ,  0.07606 ,  0.5664  ],
   [ 0.07672 ,  0.06926 ,  0.5946  ],
   [-0.241   ,  0.2419  ,  1.249   ],
   [-0.1318  ,  0.289   ,  1.182   ],
   [-0.1482  ,  0.2822  ,  1.199   ],
   [-0.1673  ,  0.2615  ,  1.217   ],
   [-0.2056  ,  0.2481  ,  1.232   ],
   [-0.17    ,  0.3072  ,  1.097   ],
   [-0.1799  ,  0.2972  ,  1.117   ],
   [-0.1886  ,  0.2866  ,  1.139   ],
   [-0.1988  ,  0.2737  ,  1.17    ],
   [-0.2035  ,  0.3251  ,  1.098   ],
   [-0.211   ,  0.3123  ,  1.118   ],
   [-0.2172  ,  0.2954  ,  1.138   ],
   [-0.2185  ,  0.2835  ,  1.169   ],
   [-0.2263  ,  0.3407  ,  1.117   ],
   [-0.2309  ,  0.3242  ,  1.134   ],
   [-0.233   ,  0.3077  ,  1.154   ],
   [-0.2331  ,  0.2912  ,  1.177   ],
   [-0.2407  ,  0.3499  ,  1.155   ],
   [-0.244   ,  0.3359  ,  1.167   ],
   [-0.2462  ,  0.323   ,  1.176   ],
   [-0.2482  ,  0.3002  ,  1.193   ]], dtype=float32)
```

Are 42 coordinates (x y z). This is the model:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation = 'relu', input_shape = (320, 320, 3)))
model.add(MaxPool2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(42, activation = 'linear'))
```

And keras throws this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (20, 42, 3)
```

How do i solve it?

Comment: It seems that, this problem for batch-wise data generation dimension mismatch error. Check the dimension of input image and signal label dimension, for every batch carefully. By doing so, i hope u can eliminate this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because your models output shape is [None,42] or for explaining [n,42] where n is number of inputs, whereas you need output to look something like [None,42,3]. For doing this you could either output 126 values and reshape them into [42,3] . You can do it like this

```
model.add(Dense(126,activation = 'linear')) ##Changing the output layer
Y_train = Y_train.reshape(-1,126)
model.fit(X_train,Y_train)
pred = model.predict(X_test)
pred = pred.reshape(-1,42,3) ## I guess you get the pattern by now
```

But this is not the best way to solve the problem, A better approach would be using convolutional layer as an output so that x,y,z components can have a correlation with each other helping the model learn fast but this may be very difficult for a beginner.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but why the n samples value have to be -1?

Comment: n would also work fine but that would mean i would have to know the size of all the arrays (bit of inconvenience) rather using the simple concept in python that indexing is cyclic i.e,                                                                                                                           a[-1] == a[n-1] . numpy extends that by using -1 it would include all the last index for you which would mean all the values

Comment: And how can i make it with convolutionals layers as output?

Comment: I am doing this to use it in real time. With convolutional layers as the output, would the predictions be faster as well and not just the training? How looks like a nn for real time and other that is not for real time?

Comment: Well i believe bythe convolutional layers as output you mean a array of values for the hand pose, and the context you have for this is the answer i gave is it correct? If yes then i believe its not possible to get a faster prediction as the no of operations will be the same but rather just the kernels would be the same hence making minuscule difference. See the networks its quite small and should not be a problem for a decent gpu accelerated pc to do the calculations. But i feel your using a it on raspberry pi or so then it would be best to code in c++ and use the arm library:) hope this helps